# is there any thing similar to "use" sql command in redis?

Tags: nosql, redis

is there any thing  similar to "use" sql command in redis ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Redis runs with multiple databases at a time (16 by default). You can use "SELECT " to change the active database.

http://redis.io/commands/select

Answer (score -2):

No. The `use` commands are typically a way to select a specific database within a server that hosts multiple databases. Redis does not generally use the same concepts to partition data stored within the server.

If its at all helpful, see http://redis.io/commands for a list of all the commands.

Comment: As pointed out, redis does in fact have multiple databases, and select is the command to choose one.